# Is homework that requires at least 12" length of parchment anything to complain about?

Tags: harry-potter

In chapter twelve of the fifth book, Snape assigns the following:

> "*Homework: twelve inches of parchment on the properties of moonstone and its uses in potion-making, to be handed in on Thursday.*"

To memory, the next chapter shows Harry and Ron complaining about both this and the obviously trivial task of keeping a dream diary.

This got me thinking, is 12 inches really anything to complain about? It's a familiar length to me, and it doesn't seem all that extreme. I'm pretty sure that I could pull out 12 inches on just about any subject. What is it that's making them think that they're going to struggle? Is there a width issue? Snape's known for his hard requirements, but this feels tiny.

Comment: Nah it's just a page, and in hand writing that's probably a less than 500 word essay, it's more likely the deadline that makes this annoying, along with the fact that it's coming out of nowhere on top of other school work that may have had long established deadlines. As students I think we all remember feeling we were drowning in hw and then a surprise assignment annoys us.

Comment: Could he have been assigning a twelve inch thick stack of parchment? (I have read none of the books and seen none of the movies)

Comment: @DaveMunger - No. He's asking them to write twelve inches of parchment scroll, almost precisely equivalent to a single side of A4 paper.

Comment: Don’t kids complain about the amount of homework no matter how much it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 12 inch essay is on its own not something to complain about. Consider that in the past they had been assigned an essay three times as long, and Hermione has written an essay four and a half times as long in tiny writing. From Chapter Nine of *Chamber of Secrets*:

> Harry found Ron at the back of the library, measuring his History of Magic homework. Professor Binns had asked for a three-foot-long composition on “The Medieval Assembly of European Wizards.”
>
> “I don’t believe it, I’m still eight inches short....” said Ron furiously, letting go of his parchment, which sprang back into a roll. “And Hermione’s done four feet seven inches and her writing’s tiny.”

The complaint about Snape's essay here is not that 12 inches is too long. The complaint is about the total amount of homework they've been assigned in such a short period of time. From later in the chapter:

> “D’you realize how much homework we’ve got already? Binns set us a foot-and-a-half-long essay on giant wars, Snape wants a foot on the use of moonstones, and now we’ve got a month’s dream diary from Trelawney! Fred and George weren’t wrong about O.W.L. year, were they? That Umbridge woman had better not give us any...”

And from the subsequent chapter:

> Now panicking slightly about the amount of homework they had to do, Harry and Ron spent their lunch hour in the library looking up the uses of moonstones in potion-making. Still angry about Ron’s slur on her woolly hats, Hermione did not join them. By the time they reached Care of Magical Creatures in the afternoon, Harry’s head was aching again.

> He swallowed a mouthful of potato and added, “I hope she doesn’t keep me too long this evening. You realize we’ve got to write three essays, practice Vanishing Spells for McGonagall, work out a countercharm for Flitwick, finish the bowtruckle drawing, and start that stupid dream diary for Trelawney?”

It seems clear that a 12 inch essay is not the issue. They have done those in the past. What they are not used to is having significant homework for so many different classes all at once right at the beginning of the term. They had been warned that O.W.L. year would be hard, and they are only now fully appreciating that.